# How to read/modify an uploaded .sav file in R markdown with Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm pretty new to using Shiny and I can't seem to get this to work.
I want to make a ShinyApp that lets the user upload a file with results of a survey, and then download a newer version with an extra column.
This extra column contains the weights for each respons because of over- of underrepresentation. I can make these calculations in R just fine.

I can't seem to simple let Shiny read the head of the .sav file.

I found this code on mastering-shiny.org chapter 9, and changed it slightly to fit my problem.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("upload", NULL, accept = ".sav", width = '100%'),
  tableOutput("head")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive(req(input$upload))
  output$head <- renderTable(head(data,n = 5L))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I just don't get how to make R 'see' the file and actually use it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data <- reactive(req(input$upload))` doesn't do anything. You're telling R to wait until `input$upload` is "truthy" (see `?req` for what is meant by that)... and do nothing.

Furthermore, `input$upload` does not contain the data that was uploaded. Instead, it contains metadata about the uploaded file. You need to load the data from the path specified by `input$upload$datapath` (Credit to @Konrad Rudolph). If it's an SPSS file, you can for example do

```
data <- reactive({
    req(input$upload)
    haven::read_sav(input$upload$datapath)
})
```

--

Whenever you call a reactive object after it's been created, you need to add a `()` to its name. This is because the reactive object is essentially a function, responding to a user's input. So your following line should be:

```
output$head <- renderTable(head(data(),n = 5L))
```